# Is a Uplay account required for Assassin's Creed 2 on consoles (Xbox 360, PS3)?

Tags: assassins-creed-2, drm, assassins-creed-series, ubisoft-connect

I'm thinking about finally buying a PS3 and I was wondering if Assassin's Creed 2 would require a Uplay account, or if Uplay is optional. I have held off on buying these games on Steam for this reason, and I would love to play them. It would also be nice to know whether or not other major Ubisoft games (Far Cry 3, Splinter Cell, etc) require a Uplay account on consoles.

Answer (score 3):

No, AC II does not require a Uplay account on PS3 (I have played the game without even knowing what Uplay was). It does support Uplay though, so if you change your mind  later on you can link the game to it.

Comment: just a comment, i think you only need uplay when playing ac3+